# listjs .search fixed position, input text goes missing

Tags: stylesheet, listjs

When using listjs from listjs.com, I add the following to my stylesheet.

```
.search{
position: fixed;
top: 119px;
}
```

and after I start typing, it matches the item, and then the text goes missing. If I delete the text, the search no longer works, and text does not appear in the search.

Does anyone know of any bugs? 
Is there a bug page for listjs?

Comment: actually, to break it, all you have to do is go to your style sheet, find the following
input {

and add 
position: fixed;

Comment: Are you adding `input class="search"` inside the element with `class="list"`? I found that made it disappear when you typed into it.